# portfolio with multiple slideshows fired by thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gallery

I found the following website using an amazing gallery/slideshow/portfolio the other day and I can't find any plugin slideshows like it. The key feature is this: separate thumbs/links load specific images into the slideshows smoothly and quickly.

http://www.blacktie.es/#!trifermed

Is there a specific name for this type of code/slideshow/gallery? All I have found so far is normal slideshows.

Has anyone used anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, the slideshow itself uses [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), a robust plugin, the version 2 is currently in development.

Comment: Anyone with anymore info or help would be so appreciated?

Comment: Thank you @Calvein i've had a look into that, much appreciated!